# React as a dependency for @vue/apollo-composable

Tags: vue.js, graphql, vite, apollo, apollo-client

I have a VueJs application using the Composition API. I want to use apollo to make queries to my GraphQL backend, but get the error `Could not resolve "react"`.

My dependencies are: `"@apollo/client": "^3.8.9"`, `"@vue/apollo-composable": "4.0.0-beta.12"`, `"graphql": "^16.8.1"` and `"graphql-tag": "^2.12.6"`.

I define my ApolloCLient in `apollo/index.ts`:

```ts
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, HttpLink } from '@apollo/client'

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: import.meta.env.VITE_GRAPHQL_URL });

export default new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})
```

It is provided to the app in a `registerPlugins` function:

```ts
//...
import apollo from '../apollo'
import { DefaultApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable'

// Types
import type { App } from 'vue'

export function registerPlugins (app: App) {
  app
    //...
    .provide(DefaultApolloClient, apollo)
}
```

When I try to run the test server with vite, I get several `[ERROR] Could not resolve "react"`, for example:

```
[ERROR] Could not resolve "react"

    node_modules/.pnpm/@apollo+client@3.8.9_graphql@16.8.1/node_modules/@apollo/client/react/context/ApolloContext.js:1:23:
      1 │ import * as React from "react";
        ╵                        ~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "react" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove
  this error.
```

I have a different application using `@vue/apollo-option` that runs without problems. I there's an elegant solution to solving this with `vue-apollo` please write that too, I simply have no experience with it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by importing from `@apollo/client/core` in `apollo/index.ts` instead.